# When I splice @Input variable, it reflects parent component's variable

Tags: angular

I have array of objects and i'm passing that into my child component. In my child component, I need to list the objects that has attribute "selected:true".

In my child component I collect the object list that has attribute "selected:true" and assign those into input variable like below

```
    let selectedList:Array<any> = [];
    for(let i = 0, len = this.inputList.length; i < len; i++){
        if(this.inputList[i].isSelected){
            selectedTransLicenses.push(this.inputList[i]);
        }
    }
    if (selectedList.length) {
        this.inputList.splice(0);
        this.inputList = [...selectedTransLicenses];
    }
```

"this.inputList.splice(0);" empties the parent's inputList variable. Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: Hey this isn't that clear. Which is the input list? from this code `selectedList` can only be an empty array...

Comment: Please clarify more your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is completely expected behaviour and nothing to do with Angular.

**The `splice()` method changes the contents of an array by removing existing elements and/or adding new elements**

So `splice(0)` essentially means remove all content from this array.

Please check more details here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: that's correct, but it's changing the parent component's variable too.

Comment: @Riyaz yes because it's the same variable, pointing to the same memory location

Answer (score 0):

It is likely passing by reference, reflecting the splice in the child back onto the parent. Essentially it is the same memory location, so splicing it in the child also splices it for the parent.

To overcome this you must pass by value.

In the past, I copied an object by including this method within it:

```
class example
{
    public example Copy()
    {
        return (example)this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

This prevented the members of the class I was using from being altered locally upon passing it elsewhere in the program.